# Error trying to start Notification Server

Tags: phabricator

I was trying to start Phabricator's *Notification Server*, but experienced the following error:

```
/phabricator/phabricator/bin/aphlict start

[2015-11-16 18:41:08] EXCEPTION: (FilesystemException) Requested path '/var/tmp/aphlict/pid' is not writable. at [<phutil>/src/filesystem/Filesystem.php:1081]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=9dd6eafb5254), phabricator(head=master, ref.master=50d158a8c4d9), phutil(head=master, ref.master=e9ed72483a14)
  #0 Filesystem::assertWritable(string) called at [<phutil>/src/filesystem/Filesystem.php:73]
  #1 Filesystem::assertWritableFile(string) called at [<phutil>/src/filesystem/Filesystem.php:89]
  #2 Filesystem::writeFile(string, string) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/aphlict/management/PhabricatorAphlictManagementWorkflow.php:140]
  #3 PhabricatorAphlictManagementWorkflow::willLaunch() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/aphlict/management/PhabricatorAphlictManagementWorkflow.php:249]
  #4 PhabricatorAphlictManagementWorkflow::executeStartCommand() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/aphlict/management/PhabricatorAphlictManagementStartWorkflow.php:15]
  #5 PhabricatorAphlictManagementStartWorkflow::execute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:406]
  #6 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(array) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:301]
  #7 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflows(array) called at [<phabricator>/support/aphlict/server/aphlict_launcher.php:23]
```

The directory in question seems to be writable:

```
ls -l /var/tmp/aphlict

total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 16 13:40 pid
```

If it matters, I'm running all operations as non-'root' on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just figured out this. As I said in the recent update, I was trying to start notification server as non-'root'. Looking again at permissions of the `/var/tmp/aphlict/pid` folder, the problem suddenly became crystal clear and trivial.

```
ls -l /var/tmp/aphlict

total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 16 13:40 pid
```

Therefore, all that needed to be done to fix the problem is to make the directory writable for everyone (I hope that this approach does not create a potential security issue):

```
chmod go+w /var/tmp/aphlict/pid

su MY_NON_ROOT_USER_NAME -c './bin/aphlict start'
Aphlict Server started.
```

Problem solved. By the way, for the Notification Server to work properly, do I need to open port 22281, in addition to already opened 22280? (Please answer in comments. Thank you!)